# The parameters of the class object are not changed

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class Edges
{
protected:
    int capacity;
    int flow;
public:
    void set_capacity(int capacity);
    void set_flow(int flow);
    int get_capacity();
    int get_flow();
 }

 void Edges::set_capacity(int capacity) { Edges::capacity = capacity; }
 void Edges::set_flow(int flow) { Edges::flow = flow; }
 int Edges::get_capacity() { return capacity; }
 int Edges::get_flow() { return flow; }
```

And I have a class:

```
class Network
{
protected:
    vector<Edges> edges_list;
public:
    void add_edge(int capacity, int flow);
    vector<Edges> get_edges_list() { return edges_list; }
 }

 void Network::add_edge(int capacity, int flow) {
     Edges temp;
     temp.set_capacity(capacity);
     temp.set_flow(flow);
     edges_list.pushback(temp);
 }
```

Next I do that:

```
Network net;
net.add_edge(100, 500);
cout << net.get_edges_list()[0].get_flow() << endl; // I see 500
```

And all is well, if I use `get_capacity()` or `get_flow()` after adding edges I'll get what I want (capacity or flow I set right now).
But if I do that:

```
net.get_edges_list()[0].set_flow(777);
cout << net.get_edges_list()[0].get_flow() << endl; // I see 500 again!
```

I see 500 again! Nothing changed. What I did wrong?

Comment: the `get` and `set` methods as you've implemented them are very much java style. You should research const and non-const methods and references and write C++ style getters and setters.

Comment: This code was clearly written by someone coming from a managed language like Java, where objects are all passed as references to the same instance. In c++, the default behavior of returning, assigning or passing a parameter is to *fully* copy the object in question (and paying the performance price). [Reference types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) are used to explicitly request that a reference to something be taken, instead of a copy. Learning when to use references and consequentially learning about `const` correctness is a fundamental part of learning c++.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `get_edges_list()` returns a copy of the private member and any changes you make on this copy do not affect the member. Maybe return a reference instead, or maybe use proper encapsulation by providing a `Network::set_flow_at(int flow,int index);`.

Comment: @nicomp why do you think it returns an adress? There is no adress in your code

Comment: erm no. `edges_list` **is** the vector. The adress of it would be `&edges_list` but dont go in that direction... you dont need to worry about any adresses

Comment: are you coming from a Java background? Just asking because that would explain your misunderstanding and if yes let me tell you that you can forget everything you learned in Java if you want to write C++, they are two very different languages

Comment: ups somehow confused nicomp with the OP, anyhow all comments have been removed... not sure if OP has the same confusion though....